# computer get suspended after clicking download button

Tags: php, download

I make php code download function. It work normally when downloading JPG file but when i use  mp3 file my computer get suspended. Here are my codes:

```
this is the form download.
<FORM ACTION="test.php" METHOD='POST'>
To download music1: 
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT"  VALUE="download">
</FORM>
```

this is the download function.

```
<?php
$FileName = 'sloth.jpg';  // the name of the file that is downloaded
$FilePath = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\sloth\\";  // the folder of the file that is downloaded , you can put the file in a folder on the server just for more order

$size = filesize($FilePath . $FileName) ;
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"". $FileName ."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". $size ."");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $FileName ."\"");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
echo (readfile($FilePath . $FileName));

?>
```

if i use mp3 file my computer get suspend after cliking the download button.

Comment: Are you saying if the user selects an mp3 file, when the script expects a JPEG, the error occurs. So you are trying to force the file upload type to be JPEG? Or do you want to allow the user to select either a JPEG or MP3?

Comment: I replace the jpg file with mp3 file. When i click download button my computer suddenly get suspended. I mean replace $FileName = 'sloth.jpg' to $FileName = 'music.mp3' (The mp3 file is already in download directory.)